# Ruby: Uninitialized constant Log4r::DEBUG (NameError) problem

Tags: ruby, log4r

While using `log4r` in Ruby, I wrote a configuration file similar to the following:

```
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'log4r'
  require 'log4r/outputter/datefileoutputter' 
  SERVICE_LOG = {
    :log_name         => 'service',
    :log_file         => 'service.log',
    :log_level        => Log4r::DEBUG, 
    :message_pattern  => "[%-5l %d] %C: %M",
    :date_pattern     => "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  }
```

when I ran it, it threw out the following exception:

```
 C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Log4r::DEBUG (NameError)
```

Why did it do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This *is* a little weird. You need to create a `logger` instance, before you can access the log level constants. Here is how it looks on irb:

```
>> require "log4r"
=> true
>> Log4r::DEBUG
NameError: uninitialized constant Log4r::DEBUG
    from (irb):2
>> Log4r::Logger.root
=> #<Log4r::RootLogger:0x101737948 @outputters=[], @level=0>
>> Log4r::DEBUG
=> 1
>>
```

In order to support [custom levels](http://log4r.rubyforge.org/rdoc/log4r/configurator_rb.html) the log levels are loaded only when the instance is loaded (arguable whether this is the right approach).

This is the code that actually loads the levels (called from the `RootLogger#instance`):

```
Log4r.define_levels(*Log4rConfig::LogLevels)
```

So in your code you can call it so:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'log4r'
require 'log4r/outputter/datefileoutputter' 
Log4r.define_levels(*Log4r::Log4rConfig::LogLevels)
SERVICE_LOG = {
  :log_name         => 'service',
  :log_file         => 'service.log',
  :log_level        => Log4r::DEBUG, 
  :message_pattern  => "[%-5l %d] %C: %M",
  :date_pattern     => "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These constants don't seem to exist anymore. What I found was this though:

```
>> Log4r::Log4rConfig.const_get :LogLevels 
#=> ["DEBUG", "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", "FATAL"]
```

Maybe have a look at their examples (e.g. `require` and `include` Log4r):

http://log4r.rubyforge.org/manual.html#outofbox

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try something like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'log4r'

L4R = Log4r::Logger.new("Logger")
Log4r::FileOutputter.new('service',
                         :filename=>"service.log",
                         :level=>Log4r::DEBUG)
L4R.add('service')
```